# How to calculate the moving average base on date and time in R

Tags: r, moving-average

I uploaded my data.
https://filebin.net/a29fn87b8wpfnos0/Plume_2.csv?t=iouc5vg7

It looks like this in a csv file format
[image]

I tried to look for a proper answer that suits my data.
I couldn't find it, it took me about a month trying by myself to solve it.

First I need to do a moving average for:

- 30 min
- 1 hour
- 1 day
- 1 week

for each PM2.5, PM10, NO2

However, I can't do that manually using this type of code:

```
Plume_2$PM2.5_30min_ <- TTR ::SMA(Plume_2$pm2.5, n=31)
Plume_2$PM2.5_1hour_ <- TTR ::SMA(Plume_2$pm2.5, n=61)
Plume_2$PM2.5_1day_ <- TTR ::SMA(Plume_2$pm2.5, n=1441)
Plume_2$PM2.5_1week_ <- TTR ::SMA(Plume_2$pm2.5, n=10080)
```

with these codes, the n  values don't fit with the date I have.

Also used this code and seems the average not working well.

```
library(runner)
dates = Plume_2$timestamp
value = Plume_2$PM2.5_Plume2

Plume_2$MA <-  mean_run(x = value, k = 7, lag = 1, idx = as.Date(dates))
```

The final output will be a plot graph containing those different moving averages.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the follwing is a satisfying solution.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("https://filebin.net/a29fn87b8wpfnos0/Plume_2.csv?t=phgmlykh")
dt[,.(timestamp,
      PM2.5_30min_mean = frollmean(PM2.5_Plume2,31),
      PM2.5_1hour_mean = frollmean(PM2.5_Plume2,61),
      PM2.5_1day_mean = frollmean(PM2.5_Plume2, 1441),
      PM2.5_1week_mean = frollmean(PM2.5_Plume2,10080))]
```

The result is shown as
[image]

Then I want to plot the result using **ggplot**. Here I choose **PM2.5_30min** as an example.

```
library(lubriate) # turn timestamp into POSIXct format with dmy_hm function
ggplot(dt2, aes(dmy_hm(timestamp), PM2.5_1hour_mean,na.rm = TRUE)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_datetime()
```

Comment: The frollmean at the beginning produced an error. However, I changed the time format, and worked perfectly.  Thanks for the ggplot hint.   I will use it instead of the norma R plot function.

Answer (score 1):

Using zoo's `rollmeanr` function along with `across` from `dplyr` can help you with this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df <- read.csv('https://filebin.net/a29fn87b8wpfnos0/Plume_2.csv?t=up70ngy3')


df %>%
  mutate(across(PM2.5_Plume2:NO2_Plume2, 
               list(avg_30min = ~rollmeanr(.x, 30, fill = NA), 
                    avg_hour =  ~rollmeanr(.x, 60, fill = NA), 
                    avg_day =  ~rollmeanr(.x, 1440, fill = NA), 
                    avg_week =  ~rollmeanr(.x, 10080, fill = NA)))) -> result

result
```

Comment: You are rock. Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot